# JAVA vesion not showing on CMD

Tags: java, windows-7

I have installed jdk1.8.0_191 and jre1.8.0_191 
i tired to get the version of java using command prompt `javac -version` and i am getting nothing.

Here is the output I get in my console:

[image]

Comment: use `java -version`

Comment: Use java instead of javac. Do you have already added path to path env?

Comment: here the screenshot of path http://take.ms/hewWj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is

> java -version

Comment: In that case check "C:\Program Files\Java". Make sure that the jdk is installed properly.

If its fresh installed restart the computer or at least relog into your user.